# using lightgbm with average precision recall score

Tags: lightgbm

I am using LightGBM and would like to use average precision recall as a metric.
I tried defining feval:

```
cv_result = lgb.cv(params=params, train_set=lgb_train, feature_name=Rel_Feat_Names, feval=APS)
```

where APS defined as:

```
def APS(preds, train_data):
    y_pred_val = []
    y_test_val = []
    for i, stat in enumerate(train_data.get_label.isnull()):
        if ~stat:
            y_pred_val.append(preds[i])
            y_test_val.append(train_data.get_label[i])
    aps = average_precision_score(np.array(y_test_val), np.array(y_pred_val))
    return aps
```

and I get an error:

TypeError: Unknown type of parameter:feval, got:function

I also try to use "MAP" as the metric

```
cv_result = lgb.cv(params=params, train_set=lgb_train, feature_name=Rel_Feat_Names, "metric="MAP")
```

but got the following error:

"lightgbm.basic.LightGBMError: For MAP metric, there should be query information"

I can't find what is the query information required.

How can I use feval corrctly and define the query required for "MAP"

Thanks

Comment: MAP is not the "Average Precision" (the area under the Precision-Recall curve). see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_measures_(information_retrieval)#Mean_average_precision and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_measures_(information_retrieval)#Average_precision

Comment: I think that "map" with lowercase is the correct parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you can put `map` (alias `mean_average_precision`) as your metric as described [here](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#metric-parameters), but to answer the question of applying `feval` correctly:

Output of the customized metric should be a tuple of name, value and greater_is_better, so in your case:

```py
def APS(preds, train_data):
    aps = average_precision_score(train_data.get_label(), preds)
    return 'aps', aps, False
```

then also include in your `params` the following: `'objective': 'binary', 'metric': 'None'`